# Torch: luajit out of memory on simple task

Tags: lua, torch, mnist

I am trying to load the MNIST dataset in the `th` repl and do mean subtraction by the following:

```
file = torch.load('data/mnist.t7/train_32x32.t7', 'ascii') 
data = file.data:type(torch.getdefaulttensortype()) 
mean = data:mean() 
data:add(-mean)
```

The last line causes the following error:

`.../torch/install/bin/luajit: not enough memory`

I am running this on a laptop with 16GB of RAM. Also MNIST has already been loaded into `data` so not sure why doing `data:add(-mean)` would cause this issue. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it was trying to print the whole matrix (which is large) to the console.

This can be overcome by doing either
`data = data:add(-mean)`
or
`data:add(-mean);` - notice the semicolon

Answer provided by Soumith Chintala on the torch gitter.